# How to get a value of a counter within a script tag

Tags: javascript

I would like to retrieve the value of a counter made by a
 script I've not access to, to show it on another webpage.
The remote webpage looks like this :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr-FR">
  <head>
    <script>
      window.changeTargetingData = {"Count":{"total":123456}, "Week":12345};
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Is it possible to get the "total" value since it is inside a script tag ? And to refresh this value, say, every hour ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you want to check the value, you can make a request to the webpage, parse it into a document, then select the `<script>` tag and examine its `textContent`:

```js
const textResponse = `<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr-FR">
  <head>
    <script>
      window.changeTargetingData = {"Count":{"total":123456}, "Week":12345};
    <\/script>
  </head>
</html>`;
/*
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then((textResponse) => {
    */
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(textResponse, 'text/html');
    const script = doc.querySelector('script');
    const objJSON = script.textContent.match(/window.changeTargetingData = (.+);/)[1];
    const obj = JSON.parse(objJSON);
    console.log(obj.Count);
```

If you can't make a request directly to the site, and you're on the front-end, you'll have to bounce the request off a server which can relay it without CORS restrictions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It's perfect. I now try to deal with the cors problem.